# Converting 32bit PCM to 16bit PCM programmatically

Tags: node.js, audio

So I have a 32 bit signed stereo PCM at 48KHz and want to convert it to 16 bit mono PCM. How would I manually convert it through the binary data? Audacity seems to do it no problem through a button click but I'd like to do it through the buffer data of the file.

Are there also any node packages that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your file from 32 bit to 16 bit programmatically, you could use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) package.
You can specify the output format to 16 bit signed PCM with the *s16le* format option and the *-ac* option to mix down to a mono stream.

For example, something like this:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg('input.wav').inputOptions([
  '-f s16be',
  '-ac 1'
]).output('output.wav')
.run()
```